# How to get full HTML of a page that has a "Load more" button in swift?

Tags: html, swift

I am using SwiftSoup to parse the HTML of a website, but there is a "Load more" button at the bottom of the page. I want to get all of the HTML as if I had pressed the load more button until there was no more to load.

Here is the website: https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/professor?tid=2776264
If you scroll down, you can see the black "Load More Ratings" button, and the HTML with more reviews doesn't load unless pressed.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/professor?tid=2776264")!
let html = try String(contentsOf: url)
```

How can I load the rest of the HTML to get it all instead of just the first couple of reviews?

Comment: You should take the request sent when click on the "load more" so you get the request to execute to get more html ;)

Comment: @DavidAnsermot This is my first time doing anything with the web; I have no idea how to do that. Do you have any resources that could help?